# Small cactus with woolly sides identification

Tags: identification, succulents, cactus

I got this cactus as a present, at least I think it is a cactus, but don't know what species it is. It is small now about 5-6 cm in height. It has hairy or woolly sides, and has multiple stems. Does anyone know what species it is, and how big it can grow? Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a Pilocereus of some sort. Kind of looks like pachycladus, but that doesn't have all the felt shown on your plant.

Comment: Could be indeed. When I google the name I find some woolly variants as well. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to help, yours is a great looking plant!

Answer (score 0):

Someone told me that this cactus is *Cereus forbesii*. I think it looks very similar, see [here](https://mld-succulents.com/products/cereus-forbesii).